# HTML input box more than one line

Tags: html

I have an HTML form

```
<form id="my_form" action="submit">
  Title: <input type="text" name="title"> 
</form>
```

I'd like the title input box to have height more than one line, instead of just one line. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer - you can't do it. Use `<textarea>` instead.